# How to get data from yesterday

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application and SQL Server database. I nave records in a database where I have a datetime column `DateCreated`.

I need to get all yesterday values, but when I try to get it I have an error.

```
var model = _orderRepo.GetAll().Where(x => x.DateCreated.Value.ToShortDateString() ==
                                      DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString());
```

Error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Take a look at methods in System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions. Their call functions in the database in LINQ to Entities queries. May be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
var model = _orderRepo.GetAll().Where(x => x.DateCreated.Year == date.Year
                        && x.DateCreated.Month == date.Month
                        && x.DateCreated.Day == date.Day);
```

Comment: You could achieve the same with `_orderRepo.GetAll().Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateCreated) == date)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, why not:

```
var model = 
    _orderRepo.GetAll()
        .Where(x => x.DateCreated.Value.Date == DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)));
```

Just as a side note, make sure you're not querying all "orders" and THEN applying a filter (which I suspect is the case), Ideally you should do this in your query.